# Sabre Bargain Finder Max API with the Fly America Act

Tags: sabre

I am building an app for a federal government client using the Bargain Finder Max SOAP API. They need to adhere to the Fly America Act: any flight that leaves the US or arrives in the US must use a US flagged carrier.

I have tried to use the `IncludeVendorPref` and included all US carriers; however, on flights such as ALGIERS (ALG) to New York (JFK) I cannot find a solution because the route may go from ALG to London via British Airways and then London to JFK via American. Because not all flights are American (because of the `IncludeVendorPref` filter I have on), it does not find this solution even though it is valid because you are taking an American carrier back from a foreign country (it is okay that you are going from a foreign country to another foreign country - i.e. Algeria to London on a foreign carrier).

Does anyone have any advice on how to handle this? Is there an easy way to adhere to the Fly America Act?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific request that will meet what you want, at least as far as I know.

There are 2 ways in which I can think you can accomplish this:

   1. By requesting 200 flights, in order to have more diversity, including the `IncludeVendorPref` qualifier for all US carriers with `PreferredLevel="Preferred"`. The bad part is that you would have to end up doing the filtering on your side. I think this would be the best way, as it would give you the most heterogeneity without loosing too many itineraries.

   2. By calling the service twice, once for the US connection and once for the trip outside. This has several disadvantages, for example it would make it really difficult to create itineraries based on the 2 responses, and it would require to create separate tickets, as those would be 2 separate itineraries.

If neither option suits your needs, I recommend you to contact the help desk to see if there would be another option that I didn't consider.